# How to catch postMessage callback in android studio WebView?

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio, webview, postmessage

**I`m trying to catch js (React Native) postMessage in android studio, I tried to use WebMessagePort and its callback, but nothing happens in callback methods, help me please!**

**Here where the postMessage occures in js:**

```
window._reactNativePostMessage = function (event, data) { window.ReactNativeWebView && window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage && window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify({event:event, data:data})); }
```

**I need to catch this onMessage callback in android studio, tried to do so:**

```
webMessagePorts[0].setWebMessageCallback(new WebMessagePort.WebMessageCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(WebMessagePort port, WebMessage message) {
                super.onMessage(port, message);
                Log.e(TAG, message.getData());
            }
        }, new Handler(msg -> {
            Log.e(TAG, msg.toString());
            return true;
        }));
webMessagePorts[1].setWebMessageCallback(new WebMessagePort.WebMessageCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMessage(WebMessagePort port, WebMessage message) {
                    super.onMessage(port, message);
                    Log.e(TAG, message.getData());
                }
            }, new Handler(msg -> {
                Log.e(TAG, msg.toString());
                return true;
            }));
```

Nothing happens in callback, help me plz!
How to catch onMessage callback?
Will be very thankful!